# Laravel checking submitted values with database before update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Ive been trying to check the fields that a user submitted from the form with the database fields to see if there was any change made
if it was let the save() query run, else send a message that no changes made

```
    public function update(Request $request,$id)
   {

        $this->validate($request, [
       'title' =>'required',
       'notes' =>'required',
            'description' =>'required'
              ]);
        $editinc = Editted::find($id);
        if($editinc > 0) {
            dd($editinc);
        }

   $data = $request->all();

        $post= Joborder::find($id);

 //before this query runs i want to check my fields with db            
 //if no changes has been this should not be executes

  $post->fill($request->input())->save();    


return redirect('/thehood')->with('success','WE DID IT.');
}
```

Additional Info :
im a newbie in Laravel so take it easy on me.

if isDirty() is possible , how ? I checked lots of questions still have no clue how to use it.

if its not possible then is there a Laravel way? something that checks and if there are difference it will **ONLY** change their value **NOT** perform a full update on every field.

**Edited** : 
this could be a way but I'm pretty sure there is Laravel way that I just don't know about it??!

```
      $post= Joborder::find($id);
    $data = $request->all();
    foreach($data as $dat => $val) {
      if($dat=="_token" || $dat=="_method") continue;
   if($data[$dat] == $post->$dat) {
      continue;
      }else{
         $post->$dat = $data[$dat];
         $post->save();
         $flag=1;
      }
    }           

     if($flag == 0 )      {
       return redirect('/thehood')->with('success','NO EDIT HAS BEEN DoNE.');
    }else{
     return redirect('/thehood')->with('success','one or more Field has been edited .');

 }
```

Comment: Save method will execute only if there are any changes. If not change is made it will not execute.You don't need to write extra code for it.

Comment: well the save executes no matter what, it does not check the fields or at least it doesn't do it for me!beside it does not tell me what exact fields where changed  in the process!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do, please enter all the fields you want to compare in the query as I am not entering all of them.

```
$exist = Joborder::where('title', $request->input('title'))->where('notes', $request->input('notes'))->first();
if($exist)
{
  //Insert into database.
}
```

Comment: to my understanding i cant tell which field is changed with this, i need to know the exact column it will going to change.beside i want to change column value only if it has been changed in input field not if there is a match!

Comment: I understand that in this case it is not possible to tell which field is changed but in your case it will only save the record if one or more fields are changed. Do you  want to know and display anywhere that what fields are changed?